# swift drag release throw

Tags: swift, drag, throw

Finding the length of an object thrown based on throwing the object, which is dragged before releasing , causing a trajectory dependent on how far the object was dragged?

I couldn't find a tutorial for this anywhere, so I decided to post it here. I think this is a very useful function. Thanks in advance.

[image: screen_trajectory]

Comment: There's a WWDC 2014 video on this very topic (session 236). Watch it.

Comment: If you were doing this in a game, you'd probably use something like [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH1-SW1). If you were doing this with UIKit objects, you'd probably use [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=206).

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?